# ThreeJS: White PNG image loaded as texture, used as material and rendered as plane has grey edges

Tags: three.js

I'm having an issue when rendering a white material in ThreeJS version 87.

Here are the steps to replicate:

1. A white PNG image that is loaded as texture
2. This texture is used to create a MeshBasicMaterial (passed as parameter map)
3. The MeshBasicMaterial is used along a plane Geometry to create a Mesh
4. The Mesh is added to an empty Scene and rendered on a WebGLRenderer with alpha: true and clearColor as white

The **problem** is that the rendered texture now has grey edges on parts that should be fully white. 
This happens with any image with white edges. I've also tried many different configurations for the renderer and the material but to no avail.

I've made a very simple CodePen that replicates the behavior as simple as possible. Does anyone know how can this problem be solved?

CodePen:

https://codepen.io/ivan-i1/pen/pZxwZX

```
var renderer, width, height, scene, camera, dataUrl, threeTexture, geometry, material, mesh;

width = window.innerWidth;
height = window.innerHeight;
dataUrl = '//data url from image';

threeTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(dataUrl);

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: threeTexture,
  transparent: true,
  alphaTest: 0.1
});
material.needsUpdate = true;

geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.z = -5;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(mesh);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true
});
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1 );

//renderer.render(scene, camera);
function render() {
  //Finally, draw to the screen
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

ThreeJS/87

**Edit:**

I think I'm lacking more precision on my post.

This is the original full alpha image:
[It might not show because its all white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkRip.png)

And this is the same image with different transparencies on 4 quadrants:
[This one too might not show because its all white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd9MA.png)

I got a helpful answer where I was told to make the alphaTest higher, but the problem is that doing that wipes out the transparent parts out of the images, and I need to conserve those parts.

Here is a copy of the codepen with the updated images and showing the same (but slight) grey edges:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ivan-i1/pen/ajQmPV)

Sorry for not being as precise the first time, any further help is even more appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set alphaTest to 0.9.. or higher.. observe the improvement.
Your star texture has gray or black in the area outside the star, which is why you're seeing a gray halo. You can fix it by filling the image with white, (but not changing the alpha channel) in your image editing tool.

Also, you should upgrade to latest three.js (r95)

edit:

I'm not sure what your exact expectation is.. but there are many different settings that control alpha blending in THREE. There is renderer.premultipliedAlpha = true/false (defaults to true) and material.transparent = true/false; material.alphaTest is a threshold value to control at what level alpha is ignored completely. There are also the material.blending, .blendEquation .blendEquation, .blendEquationAlpha, blendDst and blendSrc. etc. etc. You probably need to read up on those.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material

For instance.. here is your texture with:

```
renderer.premultipliedAlpha = false;
```

notice the black border on one quadrant of your texture.

https://codepen.io/manthrax/pen/KBraNB

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @manthrax but I really need to keep the transparency on my images. Also the black around the texture I haven't seen it on my images but a peer did see it on the **result** of ThreeJS render.